# Как установить hub в git bash?

Tags: установка

Здесь https://hub.github.com/ есть документация, как установить hub, для разных менеджеров, но для bash из командной строки не нашёл.

Можно ли прямо из консоли bash установить hub?

Если нет, то как установить hub в bash проще всего?

Comment: Установка куда? Вы смотрели [ссылку](https://github.com/github/hub) на этой же странице? Там указаны как установить для той или иной ОС.

Comment: Мне не понятно как это сделать.

Comment: Поэтому и спрашиваю, можно ли это сделать из консоли bash.

Comment: ОС windows, vs code, bash.

Comment: Как в моём случае установить hub?

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно.

Подробные инструкции для конкретных ОС и способов установки указаны в документации на GitHub: https://github.com/github/hub#installation

Comment: Из той инструкции не понятно.

Comment: У меня windows, vs code с консолью bash.

Comment: Могу ли я из консоли bash установить hub?

Comment: Если нет, то как нужно сделать в моем случае?